# Data Structure Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am looking for advanced Data Structure Implementation in C++ . 
I am reading "Algorithm Design Manual", this book written primarily for grad students, best for someone who already know theory, we need something practical;

Comment: Can you give an example(s) of more advanced data structures which you need?

Comment: You are looking for something advanced but written for someone that does not already know theory? Maybe you should start with a non-advanced book.

Comment: Something that you can't find in Knuth? I don't understand your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the "Algorithm Design Manual" [companion site](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/)? It has a bunch of data structure libraries.

Here is the listing for C++
`http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/implement/C++.shtml`

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://opendatastructures.org/ods-cpp.pdf) is a free book discussing some data structures in C++, up to Hash Tables, Red-Black trees, scapegoat trees, etc. Have a look, it's in pdf form.